# AWS ALB : Rule priority

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want routing for "/module/path1" to one pool of instances and all other paths in that module "/module/*" to another pool of instances.

I want to know whether setting highest rule priority for "/module/path1" than "/module/*" solves my requirement.

I read the documentation but didn't understand whether it suits my requirement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Priority" is used here to mean "order of evaluation" or "sequence."

Thus the "highest" priority is rule #1 even though "1" is the lowest number.

> Each rule has a priority. Rules are evaluated in priority order, from the lowest value to the highest value.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules

So, in your case, `/module/path1` needs a *lower* priority index than `/module/*`, because you need to evaluate `/module/path1` *before* evaluating `/module/*`.  If `/module/*` is evaluated first, then `/module/path1` will never be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am aware of the order of evaluation. I just wanted to know whether it is at all possible. Your answer clarified my doubt. Thank you very much.

Comment: the final statement that the OP's case needs a lower priority was misleading to me with what you say at the beginning. The case should be evaluated first, and thus have the highest priority / lower number. But thanks in the end it clarified it for me too ;)